# How do I reference javascript imports globally?

Tags: javascript, datatables, phoenix-framework, es6-modules, esbuild

I'm setting up a fresh web project in Phoenix with Elixir.  I'm coming across an issue with using Javascript that is imported inside of `app.js` inside of other javascript files I wish to import.

I've installed DataTables.net inside of the application with:

```bash
npm install datatables.net-dt --save
```

and wish to use it inside of my `app.js` with an import statement, like this:

app.js

```js
import '../vendor/myjquery'
import DataTable from 'datatables.net-dt';
import '../vendor/mydatatable'
```

mydatatable.js

```js
console.log("dataTable?")
new DataTable('#charges-table');
```

myjquery.js

```js
import jQuery from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = jQuery
window.$ = jQuery
```

The problem here is that this doesn't work and gives me the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: DataTable is not defined
    <anonymous> http://localhost:4000/assets/app.js:15971
    <anonymous> http://localhost:4000/assets/app.js:15981
```

The tricky part is that if I import the DataTable inside of the file that is using it, there's no problem. Though, this seems like a terrible imposition.  How would I define the DataTables import globally to be used throughout the site in other `.js` and `.html` files?

Comment: No, you have to import stuff into every module. There is no "global" and trust me that's a good thing.

Comment: (Well there is a global, but it's protected by adorable kittens who want you to leave them alone.)

Comment: What you *can* do is have an intermediate module that imports a bunch of useful things, and then turns around and exports them as an object with all the different imports as properties. That way your other modules can import from the intermediary, with `import { Thing, OtherThing, Etc } from "./intermediate.mjs";`

Comment: Listen to @Pointy, he speaks truth and has a fondness for cats rendering him a right honorable fellow. Just to add to what he said, do not assign jQuery to the window object. You're defeating the point of using modules and your begging for things to conflict.

Comment: @Pointy Hmm well if it's generally accepted that it's a good imposition then I can accept it as well.  I'm coming from only working on Phoenix applications with webpacker.

Comment: @AluanHaddad how should I be configuring Jquery then?  Just importing it whenever i need to use it?

Comment: This kind of problem is solved with bundlers. For example in Rollup you can write a transform hook that generates imports automatically. You cannot replace imports if you want real modules and treeshaking. Myself I use `acorn` to get exports from a module and brutally inject them in the `load` hook.

Comment: @Thomas exactly. I understand that it is a burden at first, but it pays dividends in maintainability and clarity. Think of it like dependency injection. It has abstractly analogous benefits.

Comment: I will add that moving from Java to Node was made very weird by the need to think completely differently about the dependency relationships of modules. At first I thought it was a mess, but I have come to appreciate it over time.

Comment: @Pointy sometimes I feel the same way in C#. I miss C++'s granularity as in `auto f() { using std::cout; cout << endl; }`

Answer (score 1):

To get access to the API throw all sites, you could do this.

```
let dataTable = new DataTable('#charges-table');
Window = this.dataTable
```

This should add a data table to the window object.

But I think a JSHook should be a better solution in this case.
Try to do something like this:

Below your imports, add this.

```
let Hooks = {}

Hooks.DataTableHook = {
  mounted(){
    let tableEl = this.el;
    new DataTable(tableEl, {
      responsive: true
    })
  },
  updated(){
    this.mounted()
  }
}
```

And in your Phoenix socket declaration, do this:

```
let liveSocket = new LiveSocket("/live", Socket, { params: { _csrf_token: 
csrfToken }, hooks: Hooks })
```

And when you need to add it to an HTML tag, do this.

```
<table id="table_id" phx-hook="DataTableHook" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Where the id should be anything you want, and phx-hook calls the hook's name declared above it.

Answer (score 0):

There are no such things as global imports in JavaScript.

Comment: Consider explaining in more detail.

Comment: See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: thank you, i am new to the website.next time i will make sure my answers are upto standard.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).